# Crash Log - need help to find the crash

Tags: ios, crash, uiimageview

I am getting the following crash log and i can't find what makes the app cash.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3790e29e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3540e97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3790dd80 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
3   UIKit                           0x373d2a50 -[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyFromLevel:withBlock:] + 152
4   UIKit                           0x373d286c +[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyWithDelayedReleaseArray:block:] + 464
5   UIKit                           0x373d263c +[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyWithDelayedRelease:] + 120
6   UIKit                           0x373d225c -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 148
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x339084b2 _dispatch_client_callout + 18
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x33908f88 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$up + 244
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x33909d88 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 160
10  CoreFoundation                  0x378e1f36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286
11  CoreFoundation                  0x37854eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
12  CoreFoundation                  0x37854d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
13  GraphicsServices                0x3550a2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
14  UIKit                           0x372cc2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
15  MixMe                           0x000cd120 main (main.m:16)
16  MixMe                           0x000cd0bc start + 36


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32c07350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333e011e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3341c96e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x360a3d4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x360a0ff4 _ZL17default_terminatev + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3540ea74 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x360a1078 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x360a1110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x360a250e __cxa_throw + 118
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3540e9ba objc_exception_throw + 90
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3790dd80 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
11  UIKit                           0x373d2a50 -[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyFromLevel:withBlock:] + 152
12  UIKit                           0x373d286c +[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyWithDelayedReleaseArray:block:] + 464
13  UIKit                           0x373d263c +[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyWithDelayedRelease:] + 120
14  UIKit                           0x373d225c -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 148
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x339084b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x33908f88 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$up + 244
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x33909d8a _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 162
18  CoreFoundation                  0x378e1f36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286
19  CoreFoundation                  0x37854eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
20  CoreFoundation                  0x37854d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
21  GraphicsServices                0x3550a2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
22  UIKit                           0x372cc2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
23  MixMe                           0x000cd120 main (main.m:16)
24  MixMe                           0x000cd0bc start + 36

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32c07d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333b7cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333b7a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333b78a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32bf7648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x339184ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3390adf4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32bf6eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32bf7048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x378e3040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x378e1d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37854eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37854d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x33e9da70 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333c230e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333c21d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32c07d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333b7cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333b7a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333b78a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32c07d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333b7cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333b7a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333b78a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3bf46534
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3bf46b88      r6: 0x1d5daa34      r7: 0x2fd33ae4
    r8: 0x1d5daa10    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0x1d59f5d0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd33ad8      lr: 0x333e0123      pc: 0x32c07350
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0x24000 -    0x36fff +MixMe armv7  <8782835ae4a33cbd9087976f2121601c> /var/mobile/Applications/F275D02E-5A9B-496E-ACEF-0630D800A949/MixMe.app/MixMe
0x2fec9000 - 0x2fee9fff  dyld armv7  <75594988728831d98e1f7c4c7b7ca29d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x31ced000 - 0x31da0fff  EventKit armv7  <8dbff0bfcf833661827a76b9adb64d70> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x31da1000 - 0x31da1fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <85e7546accc23ae1a973da4758512b7f> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x31db3000 - 0x31db3fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <993c9bfe8bf031548b9ddba63cc17015> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x31dd8000 - 0x31e06fff  Security armv7  <be87724ccad837479efd45ca9f2c6b2c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x31e07000 - 0x31e1dfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <f167dacec44b3a86a8eee73400ff7a83> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x31e3c000 - 0x32014fff  ImageIO armv7  <fdfa8aa6307235b29435e5c8f6bc9819> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3201d000 - 0x32430fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <0cb7a12beb3d32c1abd1834be8328b7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3243f000 - 0x32509fff  Celestial armv7  <1a048f93218d3551984b2d07e884694c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x32516000 - 0x3251bfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <7bde3532f2953f3894eb725379575926> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x325bf000 - 0x325c1fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <e57152bacb36350e8a023e0c1b540a0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x325c2000 - 0x32648fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <d45dc8901531343caf9b7e703d3eba50> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x32649000 - 0x32736fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <faa5abb937e3306ab87c7f7c38315839> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3273b000 - 0x32792fff  SAObjects armv7  <93fe8149b03538edb4b78bd374050a00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SAObjects.framework/SAObjects
0x32862000 - 0x32885fff  MobileSync armv7  <986186369add34f1be231f5a47d2fd2c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x32886000 - 0x32899fff  MediaStream armv7  <5a61a18eb84c3c45b5fe72c0d4ed0da8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
0x328a2000 - 0x32927fff  MessageUI armv7  <acd711b4e9cb3bdba768a884c4d6976a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x32928000 - 0x3292dfff  Marco armv7  <755b00548c863f939bf1409f03f2b3ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3292e000 - 0x329abfff  HomeSharing armv7  <9126a007a413357b8c0275cc505cb197> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x32ab8000 - 0x32adefff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <134c41c587fb33dca014bd525f68a0c7> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x32adf000 - 0x32b17fff  Preferences armv7  <7f5abc69d8773b78a90953d4702337d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Preferences
0x32b18000 - 0x32b35fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <4abccf75caf33fa5a0c6037b2e1c5f41> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x32b4c000 - 0x32b55fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <5258dce78afc3fd7934a5674b92ad785> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32b56000 - 0x32cfcfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <6b14c224c0e0306aa9084679ec6a99d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x32cff000 - 0x32d49fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <a361a382693032b9bdfb2860033b3024> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x32d4a000 - 0x32deafff  UIFoundation armv7  <795a2f216cc3379c95eb645c633cc527> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x32e55000 - 0x32f3cfff  CoreMediaStream armv7  <f73b3cbd58613a6d849055e49e04b8a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x32f3d000 - 0x32f44fff  MobileIcons armv7  <c7b5eb7ec2283f0b9611448ddccdd352> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x32f87000 - 0x32fd0fff  IOKit armv7  <c4786e65ac913839b1bb3b85a9c951fa> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x330a4000 - 0x339d3fff  WebCore armv7  <cd34aedf72653d1dbef6b14fdfd0c053> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x33b80000 - 0x33b85fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <15aa2c3c8d523273913d4fc6717d3b7c> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33bdd000 - 0x33d1bfff  vImage armv7  <a7fd7fcd7041356db2ca297402ab6e8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x340dc000 - 0x3410afff  ToneLibrary armv7  <eccac0a42bbf3705aa5871a98f5dcad8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/ToneLibrary
0x3411e000 - 0x3412ffff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <a3d025234d1a3880a0e5f87879633ee0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x34130000 - 0x34135fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <3a351ca1d4ae3146a787f3e13564294b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x34136000 - 0x34138fff  OAuth armv7  <d3e2bc9ae64b31f0a89c52dc1c2797fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x34146000 - 0x34149fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <e6b6ae9d4f5f3831a40fcc370afc1429> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x34151000 - 0x3420afff  Message armv7  <c854843dec583b33a72a9fe047d20f0c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x3421d000 - 0x3421dfff  vecLib armv7  <66204595f7653ef29e5e26cb8629177a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x3421e000 - 0x3422afff  AccountSettings armv7  <0b7524e9a8ef36bf9e9f6a5c445478af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x342c5000 - 0x342c6fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <46cd200d99323aebbf6d81e5fb16424f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x342ed000 - 0x34330fff  ImageCapture armv7  <d6bb733655eb36a983e1d583cd5a5301> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageCapture.framework/ImageCapture
0x34331000 - 0x3436bfff  iTunesStore armv7  <4ff9158eb0583316b34506904b21a4f3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x34378000 - 0x344c6fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <262f509dae9f3c128f25163a7029685b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x344c7000 - 0x344e4fff  TelephonyUI armv7  <d8c2944a65033ea0a0662ca6ca52b221> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x34500000 - 0x34501fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <6a0dd04f0710329b9c1722db2235f5c3> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x34502000 - 0x34502fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <a04b639c18593885bd81bfa623a6f07c> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x345c5000 - 0x345ccfff  OpenGLES armv7  <e035b741746c316dba8f1e59a568bf17> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x345e0000 - 0x34616fff  MIME armv7  <32427c81a9933c4796d1a37a88a3ac44> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x34617000 - 0x34715fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <5224e803eca737a4b2c6451d136b3d28> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34716000 - 0x34721fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c5879083e8693aba827c78a32abe2391> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x34722000 - 0x3472cfff  IAP armv7  <6703a23c7d263f33992f15c7f407b50a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x34894000 - 0x3489bfff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <6e39f8511ecc3c3489829714eb6fde12> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3489c000 - 0x34a51fff  CoreData armv7  <a42aa4f0f01833c390bc8c6c394dda1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x34a52000 - 0x34a57fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <021ff140d6003f3281dfa29b79fa9e6e> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x34a58000 - 0x34b46fff  GeoServices armv7  <6af26ce81030330b97122ba8c1deaaa2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x34b7b000 - 0x34c90fff  QuartzCore armv7  <d96571a6986c3012b315cb860f4d65ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34cb5000 - 0x34d32fff  Social armv7  <e723e791cd6434ab8be83c52f3ad2180> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
0x352b1000 - 0x352c4fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <c5a5f03138353747b539e620ef2bb5c0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x352ce000 - 0x3530bfff  FTServices armv7  <aa7fe75a69d538b2a80efa63e3484b2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x3530c000 - 0x353b9fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <ef245c0afc113f54b6f30921671edab2> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x353ba000 - 0x353bbfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <3a149b4730663b1ea84e4a0a68ccc689> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x35481000 - 0x35481fff  Accelerate armv7  <22bee3e96cbc3538bfc50ca5be618cc0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x354cf000 - 0x354d1fff  MessageSupport armv7  <44d449b4959a33b99d4ab4a9cd161ee6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x354d3000 - 0x3551ffff  QuickLook armv7  <ac70bd1a745e3402b9bcd484f34c4203> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x35520000 - 0x35548fff  PrintKit armv7  <a8ef6136b9773d42ac20f7eb54279039> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x35549000 - 0x35578fff  BulletinBoard armv7  <9c82497b35e5351cbf696f30de01d81e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BulletinBoard.framework/BulletinBoard
0x35584000 - 0x355ddfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <ad4c53081a263f0d96f63b9a80f2ae91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x35633000 - 0x35642fff  CoreVideo armv7  <092f3aa965803a1aaea69af2ac5143f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x35674000 - 0x3568afff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <9b3fd56781103f209be2c43e48c1efc9> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x35698000 - 0x356fafff  CoreText armv7  <4a0bece315e9316fa1aa1b5923740f55> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x356fb000 - 0x35730fff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <ebd023957d853fa8bd35309592e92dac> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x35d60000 - 0x36015fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <dd6f3958c3d536d6be90836682d2ffee> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x360f9000 - 0x3637efff  MediaToolbox armv7  <a1df6dd0733233d3b1cba9cddf3991f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3637f000 - 0x36444fff  CFNetwork armv7  <3e973794a4d13428bb974edcb2027139> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36457000 - 0x3646ffff  EAP8021X armv7  <034c653573c233f08edf67e516d66097> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x36486000 - 0x369d9fff  UIKit armv7  <98789fe7c21b3fe0bf5c0bb36648147f> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x369da000 - 0x36a52fff  IMCore armv7  <552805a4634630bbaad2bc9d862d7196> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x36a58000 - 0x36a5cfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <6a8f59f89218372d9f24c4193a179008> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x36a5d000 - 0x36b8ffff  CoreFoundation armv7  <e30fc309df7b3c9f8ac57f0f6047d65f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x36baf000 - 0x36bb1fff  TCC armv7  <f641dd0500fa3f0087d93da665ea84b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x36bb2000 - 0x36bc0fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <d0fb0eda6cb53a4da859d598c59e7522> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x36bc1000 - 0x36c26fff  CoreMedia armv7  <d227864b757e3a7ea5d7d96dcbb948fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x36c27000 - 0x36c28fff  DataMigration armv7  <25f8874067393208acc083124bc3eb86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x36c29000 - 0x36c35fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <a3bba3842596315a81aa171a8bbda7b5> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x36e24000 - 0x36e3ffff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <6e5f3b4c18e137e0a464fe13095b7dab> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x36e40000 - 0x36e49fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <43de6d03af0838f2a1eeec10d4149e9d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x36e4a000 - 0x36e5cfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <131d8cf4df333df3b8487ef93438e27c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36e5d000 - 0x36e61fff  IOSurface armv7  <1f598a3806073bdaa906c51dccc9429e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x36e62000 - 0x36e68fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <690aaa493b5c3f9582499f174adf4964> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x36e69000 - 0x36eddfff  ProofReader armv7  <cc89a352199a393ba0e46af69e670ef9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x36ede000 - 0x36fb6fff  StoreServices armv7  <9da3466c9cf13402a9f0412065f0ada7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x37039000 - 0x371d1fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <45ee55956c693d8cb16dc4c4e85075e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x37258000 - 0x3725bfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <20bde7d58a573f2fbd5d6458d4e50ef8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x3725c000 - 0x3726dfff  Accounts armv7  <07b95faa96e73ffeb52694cbad7f3528> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x3726e000 - 0x37275fff  XPCObjects armv7  <5bc4f7282e9d3945a6c1885217670667> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x37276000 - 0x37321fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <fba51e235adc368b8132db578723a8fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x37337000 - 0x37354fff  CoreServicesInternal armv7  <0162575a2e8b35d2915faee400c2bf30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x3739f000 - 0x373f5fff  CoreAudio armv7  <a3a2eb3a29443b42a23aa8ecb1232846> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3741a000 - 0x3741dfff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <2a9fe0b48f473d0f8fe2bf076cd12753> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3743a000 - 0x37458fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <012ed1a1f54a3d6d836e2836781d4f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x376f1000 - 0x377abfff  AddressBookUI armv7  <5c030d99a0113ceda2ae375d348e4cdb> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x377fa000 - 0x377fefff  CoreTime armv7  <64b6ebc5f456385499036668607d6546> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x377ff000 - 0x37816fff  BackBoardServices armv7  <e3eb5191f83339a1abad4c332c1b9d83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x37817000 - 0x37830fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <e1f8d258d02c344cb0d17cec31818d3f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x37831000 - 0x37837fff  XPCKit armv7  <f5f6cb3e6f353b42ae56f748811ab2c5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCKit.framework/XPCKit
0x37859000 - 0x3786efff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <9fbb123276823c2383fc34b7a55404d7> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x378d5000 - 0x3792afff  CoreTelephony armv7  <54708e241c5c3e2297c2fca0d685497d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3794f000 - 0x37955fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <6c1c1aaf9a3537d7ada4b519d14da7ab> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x37956000 - 0x379ddfff  CoreMotion armv7  <537e5776244f3ef5a355f8fd14a72a22> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x379de000 - 0x37a37fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <d831f1f9285535acac5035a29d84aaaf> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x37a38000 - 0x37a58fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <7f6f63b31f333c41952f685fdd54a6cb> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x37a7d000 - 0x37a99fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <7b2a25c750063de480f6a691f716b9d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x37aa3000 - 0x37aa3fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <1fd63e8305ab3ca190b1ef6ab2555f9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x37bd9000 - 0x37e5ffff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6a4804d0e35e362dbad6f047c25227ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x37e80000 - 0x37e8ffff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <5c91ef875c5931a1a26e227ddfd7262d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x37f0f000 - 0x37f1cfff  ApplePushService armv7  <60dbc7ab243435e099e19bdd3fa83dbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x37f1d000 - 0x37f68fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <55a7612b28c43cfcad7089b688591b80> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x37f69000 - 0x37fa6fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <7db25f3d55b93f31868e37326fba1e57> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x37fb9000 - 0x37fc0fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c1a469c6ca4a3718bef325ec0f4e1885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x37fc1000 - 0x37fc9fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <359ccc7700c93d58adbbd74ecfda80d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x37feb000 - 0x37ff5fff  MailServices armv7  <f31a7844317a3f2484cffe092e9fd7c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x38293000 - 0x3829cfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e51cbfefefbc30b6b47d99739123033e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3829d000 - 0x382a3fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <a81d768a49cf37a1a111594d39cea3fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x382aa000 - 0x382d7fff  MobileAsset armv7  <23e6b8ea85dd3dea84d8c295b4777753> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x382d8000 - 0x382f5fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <8e4d21f987d4334e927222c28ff1130b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3833e000 - 0x3841afff  WebKit armv7  <73fa195f63bc32c29060ac0fecabdca6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3859c000 - 0x385b1fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e79b59a3406f34d9b37f8085955115ce> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x385e9000 - 0x385e9fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <8a2e3a8fdf9335e2867a33e2d1a9baf8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x385ff000 - 0x3863afff  AppSupport armv7  <74ed50d2f7d23ce696b029dd817749c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x3863b000 - 0x3863ffff  FTClientServices armv7  <13aa63aa5e2e348ea289e0fd16585890> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x38640000 - 0x38778fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903960bfcfe93adb943752851f88491e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3877a000 - 0x3877afff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <f2cad3bd15f63f448a9c5be732c65819> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3877b000 - 0x3877cfff  CoreSurface armv7  <b3f9d4e8dd803a48b88c58a0663d92a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x38a5e000 - 0x38b44fff  AVFoundation armv7  <23a8a62a06b03cbcbe7659918951c9f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x38b45000 - 0x38d08fff  Foundation armv7  <2e1ac190c4f837e2a1059043dd7b1c63> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x38df2000 - 0x38dfbfff  MediaRemote armv7  <dbc251adcad43e72a31427f836a060cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x38e00000 - 0x38e06fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9e8bfe02e370375ea8439ab895528982> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x38e07000 - 0x38e2bfff  Bom armv7  <c76b4156e0463ecb922608d44c126d86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x38e2c000 - 0x39249fff  TextInput armv7  <ee57be9a7f723604afa6f27f85ea8b1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x39278000 - 0x39290fff  AssistantServices armv7  <a1444bc3ce433abb8dad2010d43cb41d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x39291000 - 0x3929dfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <e98708fbfa683df2a91d45dc765071a7> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x392cf000 - 0x39418fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <0253932c1b9038a0849ef73c38e076ca> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x39421000 - 0x39432fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <22255260ec6436d19176696422441c40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x39435000 - 0x3948dfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <9d006173bfcc3001b45c44b8e78833ed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3948e000 - 0x394a1fff  AirTraffic armv7  <b588b9fdc83d369db76f1ad5ebf2a4fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x394a2000 - 0x394ddfff  iCalendar armv7  <d5f593ead35b38a98d6cfd4a243e0172> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x3955e000 - 0x3959afff  DataAccess armv7  <bd40f7ec5a9c3df7b4a575fffc25c14f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x395d7000 - 0x395effff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <be3d5625aed733ffb2d53400655fe110> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x39607000 - 0x3963afff  AppleAccount armv7  <2af09d814a5a382192613b68b9327d49> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x39640000 - 0x39661fff  libarchive.2.dylib armv7  <7f34860fb038355c8b54b6098be55b46> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x39664000 - 0x3969afff  MMCS armv7  <4cbc5fa9369231f392390328d492488a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
0x3969b000 - 0x3969bfff  TextInput_he armv7  <eaf52ca9fcb33378b1488dd98b287de2> /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_he.bundle/TextInput_he
0x3969f000 - 0x396ddfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <bfc75ceef01e366e8335949abf037d4b> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x39713000 - 0x39743fff  ContentIndex armv7  <25cc27c7fdac34e6ae5e057c048a3e21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3974d000 - 0x39754fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <257ecb171a363e4298a63f72d7fffea2> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x39b23000 - 0x39b38fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <3afeeea531013420af75315d8d6dd332> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
```

This app dealing with many images and 3 scrollview form a plist file. 
and i can't find what is wrong in the crash log, and what object is making the app crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that you seem to be doing a fast enumeration over a collection while changing it (__NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler) as a response to a low memory notification (_performMemoryWarning).

In other words, in your low memory handler you're probably iterating over a collection of [something] and changing the collection while you're looping over it. Perhaps you're looping through some kind of cache and trying to remove the keys from the cache in the loop?