# iOS - Decipher stack trace of iOS crash related to low memory

Tags: ios, memory

I'm seeing a crash occur more often among end users of my app. Stack trace is attached. In response to the memory getting low, from my research it sounds like the OS raises an event, which can be handled by a view controller by overriding didReceiveMemoryWarning. I think the next few function calls in the stack trace are the result of this bubbling up the view controller stack.

My question is - **what exactly is causing the crash?** Is it something in the stack trace throwing an exception, causing the crash? Or is the crash a result of failing to properly address the memory warning, so the iOS stops the app? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: _NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler error means that collection is being mutated while it is fast enumerated (e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608173/nsfastenumerationmutationhandler-crash for more details).

Comment: Since it all happens in Apple's framework code, it is hard to say what's the root cause. Try to check your code where you may change view controllers hierarchy and see when that can be a problem. Or may be you do some of that in background thread - messing with UIKit in background often leads to very weird behavior and eventual crash.

Comment: Higher in the call stack is _performMemoryWarning, which I understand is triggered in the system in response to low memory. So can you elaborate on how my application code could be responsible for the issue?

Comment: As I mentioned above - try to check if you change view controller hierarchy in response to a memory warning (e.g. remove child view controller, pop controller from navigation stack etc). Here's a question with a similar problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553734/crash-log-need-help-to-find-the-crash

Comment: Thank you, that link does appear to be the same issue. So there are two threads modifying the same collection (presumably a collection of view controllers) - my application thread, and this system-level thread - and the application thread is mutating it in a way that crashes the system thread?

Comment: Yes, **something** mutates collection of view controllers unexpectedly, not sure about multiple threads. But if you ever do that from background thread in your code, that's definitely wrong and that would be what I'd start looking for

Comment: After some looking, it looks like I do have a view controller with an override implementation of didReceiveMemoryWarning that pops the current view controller from the stack. So that is most likely the culprit. Is there any way I could verify this without just causing didReceiveMemoryWarning to be triggered over and over and hoping the crash occurs?

Comment: You can simulate memory warning in simulator: "Debug" -> "Simulate memory warning" - that should trigger all system logic for you, so you should be able to reproduce crash and verify fix afterwards

Comment: That simulator feature just causes the system to call didReceiveMemoryWarning. I'm not having any trouble getting that function to be called without that feature. But I can't get the race-type condition where the array is being mutated while iterated over to happen.